# Shuffle map stage failure with indeterminate output: eliminate the indeterminacy by checkpointing the RDD before repartition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, apache-spark-sql-repartition

I'm running into an issue with a Spark job that fails roughly every 2nd time with the following error message:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: A
> shuffle map stage with indeterminate output was failed and retried.
> However, Spark cannot rollback the ResultStage XYZ to re-process the
> input data, and has to fail this job. Please eliminate the
> indeterminacy by checkpointing the RDD before repartition and try
> again.

This happens on [Databricks 13.3 LTS](https://docs.databricks.com/en/release-notes/runtime/13.3lts.html) (based on Apache Spark 3.4.1). I started out by step-wise eliminating calls to `repartition(...)` until there was none left, but I still receive the above error. My next hypothesis was that it's due to [adaptive query execution](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/sql-performance-tuning.html#adaptive-query-execution) (AQE) which may change partitioning on-the-fly. But turning off AQE didn't help either.

What else could be leading to the above error if not explicit calls to `repartition` or AQE, and what can be done to prevent it?

Comment: @thebluephantom In order to follow the advice as mentioned in the error message I would need to know where to `checkpoint` in the first place. But after no calls to `repartition` left, it's unclear to me where that would be.

Comment: Hard without showing code. take your point.

Comment: Perhaps a more productive approach would be to try and find out why _A shuffle stage ... was failed and retried._ i.e. there must be some sort of error in one of the prior stages.

Comment: @mazaneicha Failures occasionally occur due to cluster autoscaling, i.e. worker nodes are provisioned and decommissioned dynamically based on demand. This is typically not a problem since failed stages are simply retried.

Comment: @MartinStuder I think you mean failed tasks.

Comment: there is some aspect such as timestamp that makes it indeterminate I suspect but hard without code.

Comment: @Martin_Studer. Apparently it does cause a problem if your reduce stage is dependent on indeterminate map. And there could be multiple reasons. Take a https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-28927 for example...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. It was solved after I removed the autoscaling both on the cluster and on disk storage.